# Is it physically impossible for a male Anopheles mosquito to bite?

Tags: infectious-diseases, malaria, vector

I know that malaria is spread through female *Anopheles* mosquitos as they require a blood meal to survive and that male ones do not bite and they survive off of nectar, etc.
But **is it physically impossible for a male *Anopheles* mosquito to bite** an organism infected with malaria?
If it is *physically possible*, then doesn't that imply that there *can* be a chance, albeit a small one, that they can have *Plasmodium* in their gut?

Comment: Just making sure - physically *possible* and therefore plasmodium or physically impossible and therefore *no chance* of plasmodium?

Comment: @bob1 I want to know if it is physically possible and therefore plasmodium.

Comment: It is physically possible to kick a football on the surface of Mars. Does that help you know whether or not there are footballs on Mars?

Comment: Thanks - the wording was confusing with the physically impossible one one line and the no words indicating either way on the next.